# validating simple e-mail using regex

Tags: java, regex

I need help with validating a simple e-mail address, like basic pretty much. In the end after the . it should only contain either 2 or 3 characters or it gives the user an invalid message, however mine isn't recognizing that.

```
Pattern chckEmail = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z0-9]+|[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z]+(\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3})");
```

Comment: If you're only referring to the TLD, then it's possible to have more than three characters as a TLD (the part at the end after the '.').  You may have to deal with [Punycode.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode)

Comment: I understand that, but the professor said the period (.) should be followed by either 2 or 3 characters. Ideally the {2,3} should work, so I thought.